# como identificar el numero mayor para este problema?

Tags: array, bucle-for

Hola no encuentro la manera de indicar cual es el numero mayor de todos:

Código:

```
package ejerciciosArreglos;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class ejercicio11 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random random = new Random();
    //Crea un array de números de un tamaño pasado por teclado, el array contendrá números aleatorios, por último
    //nos indica cual es el mayor de todos.
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int contador = 1;

    System.out.println("Ingrese longitud del Arrays");
    int longitud = scanner.nextInt();
int mayor = 0;
    int numeros[] = new int[longitud];
    for (int posicion = 0; posicion < numeros.length; posicion++) {
      numeros[posicion] = contador;
      contador++;
      int value = random.nextInt((10 - 1) + 1) + 1;
      System.out.print("[" + value + "]");

    }


  }

}
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Qué has intentado hacer para encontrarlo?

Comment: me parece que esta pregunta ya se ha hecho al menos un par de veces.

Comment: Y donde estas buscando el mayor?